# Python 3.0 testing code receiving syntax error where there shouldn't be one

Tags: python

```
def distinct(y):
    s = str(y)
    for digit in s:
        if s.count(digit) > 1:
            return False
    return True

f = open("s1.15.in", 'r')
year = int(f.readline()) + 1
while not distinct(year):
    year = year + 1
print (year)
```

I'm receiving the syntax error on the "f" variable and I'm not sure why. I'm super new to Python.

Comment: voted to close. cannot reproduce. do you do this in the console or from a file?

Comment: Why can't it be reproduced? what am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Well, for starters, you didn't answer to my question.

Comment: I may be. I did it in the IDLE console

Comment: This is valid Python code even in 2.x...

Comment: Sorry Karoly, didn't see the second half of your question.

Comment: You pasted the code into the IDLE console directly? Try pasting it into a script and running the script.

Comment: It seems like it should be valid, I'm thinking it might have to do with the spacing or ending after the "return True" and before the "f"

Comment: Can you paste the Traceback? Are there any non-printable characters in there? `cat -A <python-file>`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mistake on a basic problem that probably will not be useful for others (too localized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE's shell is not meant for pasting code. Create a new script file (File → New Window) and run that script (Run → Run Module); it'll work fine.

Comment: THANK YOU! I didn't realize that was how it worked. I'm sorry.

Comment: @user2756382: eh, no problem. People make mistakes especially when new. (Incidentally, you'll find editing your code is a lot easier in a script window :)